# Subplots in a single plot for common row elements

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Is it possible to make subplots in one plot for common row elements to show the distribution of the values?

Suppose I have a dataframe which looks like the one below. I want to make a distribution plot for all the values coming under cut-off 0, then 1 and so on.

```
cut_off    number 
0           5
0           5
0           6
1           5
1           8
1           7
```

Thanks

Comment: `sns.scatterplot(x=df['cut_off'],y=df['number'],hue=df['cut_off'])` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "distribution plot"? A histogram? A density plot? or other?

Comment: A density plot.

Answer (score 0):

```
N_plots = len(df['cut_off'].unique())

fig, axs = plt.subplots(N_plots, 1)
for (cut,subdf), ax in zip(df.groupby('cut_off'),axs):
    ax.set_title(f'cut off = {cut:d}')
    sns.distplot(subdf['number'], ax=ax)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]